# Get the Content of Field from JSONObject Data

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to get the Content in the "hits Array" beginning with "target" until "text" from this String JsonData as bellow ,
I get this JSONData  from elasticsearch server,

```
String holdedEntity = 
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "try1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "target" : {
            "br_id" : 0,
            "wo_id" : 2,
            "process" : [
              "element 1",
              "element 2"
            ]
          },
          "explanation" : {
            "an_id" : 1311,
            "pa_name" : "micha"      
          },
          "text" : "hello world"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Result should look like this :

```
String result = 
{      
          "target" : {
            "br_id" : 0,
            "wo_id" : 2,
            "process" : [
              "element 1",
              "element 2"
            ]
          },
          "explanation" : {
            "an_id" : 1311,
            "pa_name" : "micha"      
          },
          "text" : "hello world"
        }
```

I tried this , but it is not giving the right result as above, please any Suggestion, i will be thankfull ,

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(holdedEntity);//convert the holdedEntity into JSONObject.

JSONObject jsonObjectContent = jsonObj.getJSONObject("target");//trying to get the content starting from "target" until the "text" .

String result = jsonObjectContent.toString(); //converting the jsonObjectContent  toString.
```

But it could not recognise the Field "target" and throw me this Failure ,

```
JSONObject["target"] not found
```

Please any Advice.
thx

Answer (score 0):

There is no `target` field at the top level; you have to get the `hits` field, then the `hits` field of *that*, then the appropriate element of *that* (since it is an array); finally, the `source` element of *that* will get you your desired result.

Comment: yes "target" is the beginning from the "hits Array" , and that what i want to start get with til the "text" . Can you please tell me how to get this Start from those two "hits" ??

Comment: Have you even *tried* to get the top level `hits` field?

Comment: yes i tried to get the "hits" , like this:                                                                                                                                                                                JSONObject jsonObjectContent = jsonObj.getJSONObject("hits");                     this gives me all Content of the "hits_array" , but i want to get the Result as mentioned above from "target" till the "text". Can you please tell me how to expand the line above so i can the get Result correctly? thx

Comment: how can i go inside the "_source" field and get all Content from it? is that possible ??Please Any Suggestion?